# Mysql table Object List to String Array by System.arraycopy got ArrayStoreException?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying example in java with help of Mysql, Hibernate.
I created 2 tables in Mysql, named table1, table2.
Each have 3 columns
`table1`.`rowindex`, `table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`
`table2`.`rowindex`, `table2`.`column1`, `table2`.`column2`

Scene is 
1. Sometimes table1.column1 value is equal to table2.column2.
2. It will find by table1.column2 value.

So query I used

```
SELECT a.column1, b.column1, a.column2, b.column2 FROM table1 a, table2 b where a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 ='Mandar';
```

It shows me accurate result in Mysql workbench.
Then I wrote java program to fetch this result & tried to print it.

I wrote table fetching function as follows:-

```
protected static List get_combined_two_tables(String string) {
    if (resultList != null) {
        resultList.clear();
    }
    flag_file = filecheckhibernate1(false);
    if (flag_file) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory("hibernate1.cfg.xml").openSession();
        if (session != null) {
            if (session.isOpen() == true) {
                try {
                    session.beginTransaction();
                } catch (TransactionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                String selectQuery = "SELECT a.column1, b.column1, a.column2, b.column2 FROM table1 a, table2 b where a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 =:name";
                System.out.println("selectQuery = " + selectQuery);
                Query q = null;
                try {
                    q = session.createQuery(selectQuery);
                    q.setString("name", "Mandar");
                } catch (org.hibernate.QueryException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (q != null) {
                    resultList = q.list();
                    session.getTransaction().commit();
                }
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                    session.close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

For print I wrote following function:-

```
                        List<?> combined_table_List = null;
                    combined_table_List = get_combined_two_tables("Mandar");
                    if(combined_table_List != null) {
                        String[] dest = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < combined_table_List.size(); i++) {
                                dest = new String[combined_table_List.get(i).toString().length()];
                                if(dest != null) {
                                    try {
                                        System.arraycopy(combined_table_List,0,dest,0,combined_table_List.get(i).toString().length());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                        if(Arrays.toString(dest) != null) {
                                             System.out.println("Arrays.toString(dest) ="+Arrays.toString(dest));
                                        }   
                                }

                        }   
                    }
```

When I run program, I got exception as follows:-

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at test_db$1.run(test_db.java:132)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Arrays.toString(dest) =[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Need help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The List returned by your get_combined_two_tables will be a a List of Object arrays, each array will represent a row returned by your query.

[Hibernate Query list docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list())

When you then try to copy this List into your "dest" String [] this will fail because the two types are incompatible.  i.e. you are trying to insert a List of object arrays into an array of Strings.

[ArrayStoreException Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)

You need to parse the Object array in your list into an array of Strings instead.

Comment: "You need to parse the Object array in your list into an array of Strings instead." How to do that?

Comment: Could you add a line to print the contents of your results?

combined_table_List = get_combined_two_tables("Mandar");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combined_table_List).get(0));

Comment: I got error 'Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
 - The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments 
  (capture#3-of ?)'

Comment: Let's try this first...
combined_table_List = get_combined_two_tables("Mandar"); System.out.println(combined_table_List);